# Problema em criar aplicação Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Sempre que vou criar um aplicação, na hora de fazer um scaffold (seguindo tutoriais) me aparece o seguinte erro:

```
C:\Users\User\Usuarios>rails generate scaffold Usuario nome:string idade:integer
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10-x64-mingw32/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `require': cannot load such file -
- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10-x64-mingw32/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (requ
ired)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10-x64-mingw32/lib/sqlite3.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in requ
ire'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.4/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
        from C:/Users/Claudanilo/Usuarios/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:141:in `require'

        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:141:in `require_
application_and_environment!'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:128:in `generate
_or_destroy'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:50:in `generate'

        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_comma
nd!'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

O que está acontecendo de errado?

Comment: Aparentemente o problema está no `sqlite3`, tem como você verificar se ele está instalado? (ps.:tem certeza que quer construir aplicações rails usando Windows?)

Comment: Rodar aplicações Ruby no Windows é uma tarefa árdua, dado que o ambiente é um pouco inóspito a essa plataforma. Se você tem a possibilidade, desenvolver em um ambiente UNIX (uma máquina virtual rodando linux seria suficiente) muitas vezes torna a experiência muito mais tranquila, evitando uma gama de erros banais.

Comment: Especificamente sobre seu erro: qual versão do Ruby estás a utilizar? O que acontece ser você tentar atualizar a versão da gem sqlite (`gem update sqlite3`)?

Comment: Bom, to rodando no Windows mais por aprendizado mesmo, porem ja estou cogitando migrar para o linux (ubuntu ou centOs). Sobre a versao: Ruby 2.2.2; Rails 4.2.1; Sobre o sqlite3: quando atualizo aparece "Nothing to Update";

Comment: Só atualizando, desisto de tentar rodar no windows. Fiz uns testes aqui numa maquina virtual minha (rodando centOs) e foi realmente muito mais tranquilo. Agradeço aos que tentaram ajudar :)

Comment: Esse é o primeiro scaffold da sua aplicação? Já rodou um `rake db:create` ?

Answer (score 1):

Amigo se você ainda quiser tentar no Windows a solução é instalar o Ruby 2.0.0 e o Rails novamente nessa versão mais antiga. Também estou estudando no Windows e tive o mesmo problema, só que o meu era ao executar o comando `rake db:create` para criar o banco de dados da aplicação. A razão desse problema é que o sqlite3 1.3.10 não é compatível (no Windows eu acredito) com o Ruby 2.2.2.